# What do you call someone who doesn't pay others back?

Tags: idiom-request

I've heard the term "Deadbeat" but I'm not sure whether this is very common for saying that someone is a bad payer. Do you guys know of other words that could be used to describe someone like that other than "deadbeat"?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/132254/9161

Answer (score 2):

Well “cheapskate” comes to mind.

The a more flowery description is “having short arms and deep pockets”...

Answer (score 2):

I might use “freeloader” or “moocher” to describe someone who takes money or other things from someone and doesn’t return what they took.